# C# MVC Get List of Models from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a List of Models which i display in the view within a form. That works so on but if i click on save i got the model back but the list is empty. Has anyone a idea?

View:

```
@model AdminFeatureSetsModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdministrationLayout.cshtml";
}

@section headerTitle
{
<div>Edit Feature Settings</div>
<br />
<br />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "AdminFeatureSets", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditFeatureSet", name = "EditFeatureSet", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="grey-border-generic" id="EditFeatureSet">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b> Feature Name</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b> Enabled</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b> Verify</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b> Enabled By User</b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <b>Enabled By Organization </b>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FeatureSets.Count; i++)
        {

            if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)
            {
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <b> @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].Enabled, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EditEnable" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].Verify, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EditVerify" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByUser, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EditEnableByUser" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByOrganisation, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "EditEnableByOrganization" })
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <b> @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name</b>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2" style="color:red">
                    <b> Not in database</b>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />
            }


        }

                <button class="btn btn-xyzmo-secondary " id="saveEditsBtn">Save</button>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:
In the function save by the foreach(model.FeatureSets) the FeatureSets (List) is always empty.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AdminFeatureSetsModel modelFeatureSets = new AdminFeatureSetsModel();
            modelFeatureSets.FeatureSets = new List<FeatureSetModel>();
            var featureInDB = DbContext.GetAllEntitiesQueryable<Feature>();

            var clazz = typeof(FeatureSet);
            foreach (var property in clazz.GetProperties())
            {
                FeatureSetModel modelFeatureSet = new FeatureSetModel();
                var feature = featureInDB.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == property.Name);
                if (feature != null)
                {
                    modelFeatureSet.Name = feature.Name;
                    modelFeatureSet.Enabled = feature.Enabled;
                    modelFeatureSet.Verify = feature.Verify;
                    modelFeatureSet.EnabledByUser = feature.EnableByUser;
                    modelFeatureSet.EnabledByOrganisation = feature.EnableByOrganization;
                    modelFeatureSet.IsFeatureInDB = true;
                }else
                {
                    modelFeatureSet.Name = property.Name;
                    modelFeatureSet.IsFeatureInDB = false;
                }
                modelFeatureSets.FeatureSets.Add(modelFeatureSet);             

            }
            return View(modelFeatureSets);   
        }

        public ActionResult Save(AdminFeatureSetsModel model)
        {

            var featureInDB = DbContext.GetAllEntitiesQueryable<Feature>();
            foreach (var featureSet in model.FeatureSets) // here the FeatureSet of the model is always empty
            {
                if (featureSet.IsFeatureInDB == true)
                {
                    var feature = featureInDB.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == featureSet.Name);
                    feature.Enabled = featureSet.Enabled;
                    feature.Verify = featureSet.Verify;
                    feature.EnableByUser = featureSet.EnabledByUser;
                    feature.EnableByOrganization = featureSet.EnabledByOrganisation;
                }
            }
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminFeatureSet");
        }
```

Model with the List:

```
public class AdminFeatureSetsModel :AdminBaseModel
    {
        public List<FeatureSetModel> FeatureSets { get; set; }    
    }
```

Model FeatureSet:

```
public class FeatureSetModel : AdminBaseModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public bool Verify { get; set; }
        public bool EnabledByUser { get; set; }
        public bool EnabledByOrganisation { get; set; }

        public bool IsFeatureInDB { get; set; }

        public List<User> EnabledUserList { get;set;}
        public List<Organization> EnabledOrginaizationList { get; set; }

    }
```

[image: View of the FeatureSetModels]

---

Edit

```
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB)
                if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)
                {
                    @*<input type="hidden" name="FeatureSets.Index" value="@i" />*@ 
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <b> @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].Enabled)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].Verify)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByUser)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByOrganisation)
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                }
                else
                {
                    @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].Enabled)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].Verify)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByUser)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].EnabledByOrganisation)
}
```

Comment: Did you try `TryUpdateModel`.

Comment: Which lists? (`FeatureSets` or `EnabledUserList` and `EnabledOrginaizationList `) And not related but remove all your `new { @id = "xxx" }` code - its invalid html.

Comment: Did i call that in the Controller ? I dont know that function.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it ist the FeatureSets List

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx. If this helps. And as said above new id is invalid. Your id will be automatically generated by the model name

Comment: @AkashAmin, That has nothing to do with it

Comment: Your `if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)` block means that your missing various properties depending on the condition so you should be generating hidden elements for the properties that you don't generate a textbox for. But textboxes don't make sense anyway - your bind to `bool` properties so it should be `CheckBoxFor()`

Comment: So the statements in the else should been hidden elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its not binding is because of your

```
if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)
```

code. If the value is false, you do not generate any form controls for that `FeatureSetModel` so you post back non-consecutive indexed objects.

By default the `DefaultModelBinder` requires collection indexers to start at zero and be consecutive.  If the 1st item in the collection has `IsFeatureInDB = false` then the collection will be empty. (if the 1st 2 items were `true` and the 3rd was `false`, then you would get only 2 items in the collection)

One way to solve this would be to add hidden inputs for each property of `FeatureSetModel` inside the `else` block.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FeatureSets.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].IsFeatureInDB ) // add this so its value posts back
    if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)
    {
        @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Enabled, new { @class = "form-control" }) // remove id attribute
        ....
    }
    else
    {
        @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name</b>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Enabled) // add hidden inputs
        ....
    }
```

Another alternative, if you do not want the objects with `IsFeatureInDB = false` to be included in the collection when you submit is to include a hidden input for the collection indexer, which does allow non-zero/non-consecutive indexers to be bound

```
if (Model.FeatureSets[i].IsFeatureInDB == true)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="FeatureSets.Index" value="@i" /> // add this
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <b> @Model.FeatureSets[i].Name</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.FeatureSets[i].Enabled, new { @class = "form-control" }) // remove the invalid id attributes
    </div>
```

Note also that you need to include a hidden input for the `IsFeatureInDB` property. Without it, the value of that property will always be `false` in the POST method and the code in your loop will not be executed

Side note: Remove the `new { @id = "xxx"` code from your helpers. Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html.

Comment: i guees its a stupid question but how i can add hidden checkboxesfor ?

Comment: You dont. Your existing `@Html.TextBoxFor()` method should be `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` - but you have added an image showing they are checboxes so I assume that's just a typo in your question. The hidden inputs just need to be `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeatureSets[i].Enabled)` which will generate `value="true"` or `value="false"`

Comment: If i add this <input type="hidden" name="FeatureSets.Index" value="@i" /> // add this and click save it redirect me to a false URL ? without this i got the right view but the model is still empty

Comment: What? - that has nothing to do with redirecting to another url. You obviously have some other problems with your code. But note that you will probably want the first option anyway (using the hidden inputs in the else block) so that your whole collection will be bound.

Comment: And I have just noticed you have not even included a form control for property `IsFeatureInDB` so that will always be false and you loop will never be executed. You need to add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsFeatureInDB)` before your `if` block

Comment: You cant just go and completely change your question and invalidate my answer. I have rolled back the changes.

Comment: Oh okay sry. I tried what you said but it didnt work. 
Where can i show you my changes ?

Comment: It does work, so your doing something else wrong. Edit your question, but add the code you have tried to the bottom so the original question remains. (note you do not need to show everything - just one or 2 of the controls - keep it simple)

Comment: And another side note - different browsers have different defaults for `<button>` elements - always use `<button type="submit" .... >`

Comment: The code in your edit will work just fine although you have not included a hidden input for the `Name` property so that wont be bound to your model and `var feature = featureInDB.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == featureSet.Name);` will fail.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping

Comment: So is it working now? I have just seen you have added your own answer with a different solution which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I found my mistake. I had a spelling mistake by my RedirectToAction. So your solution works perfect. Sry for the mistake